# let $ a,b \in (0,1 )$ then prove that $a b (a b + 1)<a + b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> let $ a,b \in (0,1 )$ then prove that $a b (a b + 1)<a + b$

My Try : $(ab)^2+(ab) < a+b $ now divided by $ (ab) $ we have  $(ab)+1 < 1/b +1/a $ now what ?

Comment: If you have $(ab)^2+(ab)<a+b$, then you're done: $ab(ab+1)=(ab)^2+ab<a+b$

Comment: Notice that $ab \le 1$ means that $a \ge 1$ or $b \ge 1$ And then $a+b>1$

Comment: @Alessandro no look we only have $ b , a \in (0,1)$

Comment: Hint: If $0<a,b<1$, then $ab<1\rightarrow ab+1<2$, while $\frac{1}{b}.\frac{1}{a}>1$ (since $0<x<1$ implies $1<\frac{1}{x}$), so $\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a}>2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac1b >2>1+ab$$